# Why isn't this push to a view controller not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

Any idea why this push to a view controller wouldn't be working?

```
-(IBAction)dismissView 
{
    RegSuccessViewController* viewController = [[RegSuccessViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegSuccessViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"push to reg success");
}
```

Comment: Many but you are not giving us enough to go on. Do you have `UINavigationController` in place, any debug messages in console?

Comment: you are not using UINavigationController :)

Comment: you have a NavigationController in your storyboard?

Comment: for that is not working :)

Answer (score 1):

There is not much info here to debug so I am going to take a wild guess and say your `self.navigationController` is `nil` here.

You can check that by applying a break point and using `[po self.navigationController]` in console.

If its is nil, you need to make sure your navigation controller is properly initialized (Might be in storyboard or if you are doing programmatically).